# Programatic Access to the Java Plug-in Control Panel

Tags: java, windows, scripting

Is there a way to access the Java Plug-in Control Panel programatically? Or at least find the places in the Windows File System where the information backing that control panel is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be eligible to look at the source code for the Sun JVM.  Then you can see it all there.

Comment: May be eligible? I believe it's been available to the general public for about 15 years.